# Drawing Marbles Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

My daughter had a math problem in her textbook that we are having a hard time understanding. You have $3$ white and $4$ black marbles in a bag and $3$ people will draw a marble and not replace it in the bag. The first person to draw the white marble wins. What is the probability that the first person will win, 2nd, 3rd? The answer given was $\frac{18}{35}, \frac{11}{35},$ and $\frac{6}{35}$.

First we were able to get these answers by using 3! and 2! but we are not sure why we would do that.

Second, if these answers are correct can anyone explain why the first person drawing against the total number would have the highest probability of winning? I would believe it to be the opposite.

Comment: The first person wins if she wins one her first pick or on her second (should the white marble not be drawn on the first "round"). The probability of this  is $3/7 + (4/7)(3/6)(2/5)(3/4)$ (the multiplication rule was used for the term giving the probability she wins on her second pick). Similarly, there are two cases where the second person can win. For the third, you can just sum the two previous probabilities and subtract from $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand a bit on what David said. Firstly, it is logical that the first person has the highest probability of winning, as that person can stop the contest before anyone else has a chance. All the other contestants' chances are dependent on all prior contestants NOT winning prior to their turn.

**Round 1**:

There are four possibilities:

1. Person A wins
2. Person B wins
3. Person C wins
4. We go to round 2.

Person A has a $\frac{3}{7}$ probability of winning flat out, as there are 3 white marbles and 7 total. There is a $\frac{4}{7}$ probability that Person B gets a draw. **If** person B gets a draw, that must mean there are 6 marbles left, 3 black and 3 white. So the probability of person B winning in round 1 is$$
\large \overbrace{\frac{4}{7}}^\textrm{A does not win}\underbrace{\frac{3}{6}}_\textrm{B wins} = \frac{4\cdot 3}{7\cdot 6} = \frac{2}{7}
$$
The same argument shows that the probability that C wins in round 1 is $\frac{6}{35}$ and the probability that round 2 is entered is $\frac{4}{35}$.

**Round 2**:

At this point there must be 3 white and only 1 black marble left (as to get here, everyone had to pick black marbles in round 1). Given we had a $\frac{4}{35}$ probability to get here, person A has a $\frac{4}{35} \cdot \frac{3}{4}$ chance of winning, and if Person A does **not** win in round 2, person B **must** as all there are left are white marbles. Person C cannot get a chance in round 2—there aren't enough black marbles.

Putting this all together we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\textrm{Person A} &= \frac{3}{7} + \frac{4}{35}\cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{15 + 3}{35} &= \frac{18}{35}\\
\textrm{Person B} &= \frac{2}{7} + \frac{4}{35}\cdot\frac{1}{4} = \frac{10 + 1}{35} &= \frac{11}{35}\\
\textrm{Person B} &= \frac{6}{35} + 0 &= \frac{6}{35}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I have a similar problem. There are 7 black, 6 white, 2 red and 1 green marble in a bag. There are four people lets call them A,B,C and D. You win if the green marble is drawn. Person A draws first and they draw in alphabetical order. What is probability that person A wins. The answer is saying 1/4 but I cant seem to get this; I tried using your method and could not get the correct answer.

Comment: That is correct, you just have to go out an extra step. The first step is that person A winns on the first draw. That has a 1/16 probability. If person A does not win on the first draw, then person A must win on the second draw, that means no one must bick the green marble on any of the first three draws. If person A still does not pick the green marble, they must get the chance on the third draw. And so on until there are no marbles left. Expanding all the nested products and sums and solving them leads to 1/4.